# How to "unsync" files from perforce client?

Tags: perforce

I have files in my perforce client which I no longer need.
Is there a way to remove the files from my client to free up the space?
I don't want to delete the client and create a new one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `sync` to any revision, including `#none`.  To temporarily remove a directory (e.g. the current directory, `...`) from your client just do:

```
p4 sync ...#none
```

If you want to more permanently remove the directory from your client (so it won't come back even if you re-sync your entire workspace), remove it from your client's View:

```
View:
    //depot/... //my-client/...
    -//depot/some_directory/... //my-client/some_directory/...
```